# what is regexp_split_to_array doing in postgres with regex: E'\\\\.'

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

Can someone help me understand what this SQL query is doing?

```
select region_code, 
       ST_Area(geom::geography) as area,
       ST_X(ST_Centroid(geom)) as long, 
       ST_Y(ST_Centroid(geom)) as lat, 
       latitude, 
       longitude 
from regions 
where regexp_split_to_array(parent, E'\\\\.') && %s 
or region_code in %s
```

More specifically I'm confused about the `where` condition:

```
where regexp_split_to_array(parent, E'\\\\.') && %s 
or region_code in %s
```

I looked up `regexp_split_to_array` here, https://www.sqliz.com/postgresql-ref/regexp_split_to_array/. From what I can tell it splits the `parent` to an array based on the regex `E'\\\\.'`.

My understanding of `\.` is it will split at every `.` but what happens when you have `\\\\`?

Suppose the `parent` field is `aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd` what is the regex supposed to do?

I've tried running:

```
select name, parent, region_code from regions where regexp_split_to_array(parent, E'\\\\.');
```

but I get the error:

```
ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type text[]
LINE 1: ...lect name, parent, region_code from regions where regexp_spl...
```

So I modified it to:

```
select name, parent, region_code from regions where regexp_split_to_array(parent, E'\\\\.') && Array['something_here'];
```

and got this:

```
 name | parent | region_code
------+--------+-------------
(0 rows)
```

Can someone explain to me what exactly the where clause is doing? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The expression splits a string by two characters, the first of which is a backslash, e.g.

```sql
select regexp_split_to_array('aa\?bb\!cc\ddd', E'\\\\.')

 regexp_split_to_array
-----------------------
 {aa,bb,cc,dd}
(1 row)
```

Note that `E'\\\\.'` is equivalent to `'\\.'` (though the former looks more professional).

```sql
select regexp_split_to_array('aa\?bb\!cc\ddd', '\\.');

 regexp_split_to_array
-----------------------
 {aa,bb,cc,dd}
(1 row)
```

It might seem the expression results from the overwork of a developer who wanted to achieve something else. However, if the query is **a python string** then it is escaped when used in `execute()` and translated to the proper

```
select regexp_split_to_array('aa.bb.cc.dd', E'\\.')
```

which splits the first arguments by a period. You can try this:

```py
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host="localhost",
    database="test",
    user="xxx",
    password="xxx")

query = "select regexp_split_to_array('aa.bb.cc.dd', E'\\\\.')"

with conn.cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute(query)
    print(cur.fetchone()[0])
```

The result is:

```
['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd']
```

Comment: Did you mean the latter looks more professional?

Comment: Perhaps, but the former is definitely more sublime ;)

Comment: Ahh, the other definition of "professional": "needlessly complicated". :P

Answer (score 1):

`E'...'` is a [string constant with C-Style escapes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS) meaning it will interpret `\n` as a newline and so forth. Anything with a leading `\` is escaped. `\\` means `\`. `\.` means `.`.

So `E'\\\\.'` is a tortured way to write `'\\.'`

Regexes also use `\` as an escape character. So `'\\.'` to a regex means to match a literal `\` and then a any single character.

`regexp_split_to_array(parent, E'\\\\.')` is just `regexp_split_to_array(parent, '\\.')`. It is splitting on `\<any character>`.

`'this\-and\-that'` will be split into `{'this', 'and', 'that'}`.

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/0S71-jJ1).

Answer (score 1):

You should move the function into the select list, if you want the results of it:

```
select name, parent, region_code, regexp_split_to_array(parent, E'\\\\.')
   from regions;
```

The construct `E'\\\\.'` creates the same thing as the simpler `'\\.'`, because with E one backslash escapes the next one.  Then in regex engine, again one backslash escapes the next one, so this overall thing splits on a literal backslash followed by any character, and swallows that "any character".  Whether this is what the person who wrote that code intended it to do, I can't say.

Answer (score 1):

Telling from %s in the query, I believe this is not a direct sql code from sql  terminal, but within a programming language wrapper, I guess it's probably wrapped by Python.

The regex pattern you are looking for is split 'aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd' by '.',

Step 1. raw sql code on [regexp_split_to_array()](https://www.sqliz.com/postgresql-ref/regexp_split_to_array/) should be

```
regexp_split_to_array(parent,'\.')
```

Step 2. PostgreSQL accept [escape string directly with E prefix](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-syntax-lexical.html), the escaped string with E prefix in raw sql code should be

```
regexp_split_to_array(parent,E'\\\.')
```

Step 3 (optional). If your code is in python wrapper, the code should be further escaped.

```
regexp_split_to_array(parent,E'\\\\\\\.')
```

See [SQLFIDDLE LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/30a5d/2)

[image]